# Projecting aggregate state in Read Model, extra logic on read side vs more data in the event

Tags: events, domain-driven-design, cqrs

Let's say, I'm using event sourcing and my aggregate root (match) builds its state from "PlayerWonPoint" and "PlayerLostPoint" events (it also has two corresponding commands). If simplified, state goes from *InProgress* to *Final*. Read side is responsible for representing points history and some stats. For tennis, for example, points would be represented as

```
MatchStarted    -> 0-0
PlayerWonPoint  -> 15-0
PlayerLostPoint -> 15-15
PlayerWonPoint  -> 30-15
PlayerWonPoint  -> 40-15
PlayerWonPoint  -> Player won the game
```

- Do I tell Read Model (using event data) what is current score
  representation, so read model will take it as given and just append
  to the table? In this case read side is very simple, but we add some
  extra data into source events that is not really required for
  aggregate itself.
- Or, we can let Read side to figure out scores representation? It will
  require extra logic which will be very similar to what is used in the
  aggregate for tracking it's current state.

Another question: if player wins the point and aggregate sees that it is a *GamePoint*, *SetPoint* or *MatchPoint*, do I record different event type for that or I just keep using only *PlayerLostPoint*/*PlayerLostPoint* events? Because, again, the aggregate can re-hydrate itself from the latter two events types. But, with only two event types read model gets even more complicated (i.e. need to track games, sets, etc.). I see no big harm adding extra even types to simplify ReadModel, potentially extra event types maybe useful for aggregate too, for example, it can skip processing all points events if last point event is "PlayerWonTheMatch"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I tell Read Model (using event data) what is current score
>   representation

I think that's the way you should go. Otherwise you should build another aggregate on read model. Cause only aggregate knows what was the score after you performed a specific action on it. Also consider that events may come out of order, or come twice. Be ready for that.

> if player wins the point and aggregate sees that it is a GamePoint,
>   SetPoint or MatchPoint, do I record different event type for that or I
>   just keep using only PlayerLostPoint/PlayerLostPoint events?

I think you should do it if your domain requires it. It gives more detailed info about the game, but make sure its needed, don't program the reality, other wise you would end up with events like: ABallBoySuppliedTennisBallToPlayerEvent which could be useless for your domain.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that supplementing events with *relevant to the domain in question* data is OK. That way Read stays simple and aggregate re-hydration will be more effective, i.e. if aggregate state (that would include the current scores) is available from the event, it can take it as given without need to re-compute state. I never faced out of order events so far, I guess it may happen when you Read side seats in the other process and communication happens over some Message bus? In my case so far Read and Write parts share process and in-process events are easier to handle.